# Cannot install macbook webcam driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: webcam, macbook

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Macbook 12" (early 2016, 1.1GHz), and the camera is not working. I tried to follow the steps:

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install curl xzcat cpio
git clone https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware.git
cd facetimehd-firmware
make
sudo make install
cd ..
sudo apt-get install kmod libssl-dev checkinstall
git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
cd bcwc_pcie
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
sudo nano /etc/modules
**add line "facetimehd", write out (ctl+o) & close**
```

but on the 2nd make install I got the error:

```
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
```

Already tried generated the x509.genkey on the root folder, but still with that issue.

Comment: Will this help: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/6d8lx1/facetime_hd_camera_on_ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

This post has a solution that worked for me:  https://victorleungtw.com/2020/04/24/install-ubuntu-macbook-pro.html

You could get rid of that error by not using modules_install in your Makefile.

Change install from:

```
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install
```

to install:

```
cp facetimehd.ko /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/extra
depmod -a
```